# After atype value , there is no date format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

When dealing with the data, it shows the date value with some problem of the format.

```
      Fuel  price   DATE
0   Diesel  1669    2014-11-06
1   Diesel  1549    2014-11-02
2   Diesel  1529    2014-11-03
3   Diesel  1519    2014-11-06 
4   Diesel  1529    2014-11-06
```

So I do this:

```
 import numpy as np
 df_diesel['DATE']= df_diesel['DATE'].values.astype(np.int64)
 df_diesel['DATE'].dtype
```

then, It could plot successfully. But the date format `2014-11-06` disappeared, transferred to `1544054400000000000`. If I did not do this, I could not merge table or plot. That is trouble.

How to merge table and plot successfully and have the date format which won't
show `1544054400000000000` again.

the code for plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline
plt.title("Analyse")

plt.xlabel("DATE")
plt.ylabel("price")
plt.scatter(df_diesel['DATE'], df_diesel['price'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share your dataframe ?

Comment: I add the dataframe now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am considering only date column,

Input:

```
    DATE         Fuel   Price
0   2014-11-06  Diesel  1669
1   2014-11-02  Diesel  1549
2   2014-11-03  Diesel  1529
3   2014-11-06  Diesel  1519
4   2014-11-06  Diesel  1529

df['DATE']= df['DATE'].values.astype(np.int64)
df
```

Output:

```
     DATE                Fuel   Price
0   1415232000000000000 Diesel  1669
1   1414886400000000000 Diesel  1549
2   1414972800000000000 Diesel  1529
3   1415232000000000000 Diesel  1519
4   1415232000000000000 Diesel  1529
```

Date has been converted into `timestamp`. To convert it back into original format, just do,

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], unit='ns')
df
```

Output:

```
     DATE    Fuel   Price
0   2014-11-06  Diesel  1669
1   2014-11-02  Diesel  1549
2   2014-11-03  Diesel  1529
3   2014-11-06  Diesel  1519
4   2014-11-06  Diesel  1529
```

Now, plot by using this,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline
plt.title("Analyse")

plt.xlabel("DATE")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.scatter(list(df['DATE'].values), list(df['Price'].values))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried the code, and it returned TypeError: invalid type promotion. It could not plot now.

Comment: In question, you said you are getting successful plot and now your problem is to get original date format back so I solved this in this way. You should do for plotting as you was doing before and to get back dates to original format, you can follow my code.

Comment: After plotting, it could not do your code to format the date.

Comment: Share your whole code I want to see where exactly the problem is.

Comment: After plotting the graph, the date already showed 1544054400000000000, how could change the 1544054400000000000 on the graph?

Comment: plt.xlabel("DATE") 
plt.ylabel("price")
plt.scatter(df_diesel['DATE'], df_diesel['price'])
plt.show()

Comment: @AAlex I have updated the reply. Let me know if there is any other issue. Please accept and up-vote.